# Generate C# classes from XML only if XML has changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, pre-build-event

I have a pre-build event on a C# project which runs xsltproc to transform some XML into C# source files.  The generated source then gets built in the normal way.  This means that the project always gets built regardless of whether the XML has changed.

Is there a way of only generating the C# classes if the XML has changed?  Is a pre-build event the wrong approach?  Would I be better off with a custom tool of some kind to turn the XML into C#?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  The XML doesn't contain serialized objects.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I added a new ItemGroup to my csproj file with references to each XML file.  I gave each item an element name of Preprocess:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Preprocess Include="Xml\MySourceXmlFile1" />
  <Preprocess Include="Xml\MySourceXmlFile2.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Later in the project file I overrode the BeforeBuild target, so that it transforms every Preprocess item into a C# source file with the same name as the XML file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild"
  Inputs="@(Preprocess)"
  Outputs="@(Preprocess->'$(ProjectDir)%(Filename).cs')">
  <Exec Command="xsltproc -o %22$(ProjectDir)%(Filename).cs%22 %22MyTransform.xsl%22 @(Preprocess)" />
</Target>
```

Note the arguments to xsltproc have to be escaped with %22.

Now the C# source file is only built if the XML has changed.  I got the approach from [this](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.532634.2) forum post.